# How to hit back button after final iteration in nested for loop ? (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So i have the back button defined just do not know where to put it or how to incorporate it. I'm trying to check all unchecked boxes in subcategories then go 'back' to categories to finish the main iterations and check the rest of the boxes, just do not know how to go about where to include the back button in the code and how.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

#navigate crunchbase & add parameters
addcolumn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator add-column-button mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary"]')
addcolumn.click()

# get items only from first list
all_categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[1]//mat-list-item')
print('len(all_categories):', len(all_categories))

for category in all_categories:
    print('-----')
    
    # select category
    print('Category:', category.text.strip())
    
    # scroll it to make it visible and clickable
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", category)
    # or
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(category).perform()
    
    # click category to display list of columns in this category
    category.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # search columns ONLY in selected category

    # it selects item only if `mat-checkbox` doesn't have class `mat-checkbox-checked`
    # and it click `label` instead of `checkbox` because `label` is not hidden by `popup message`
    columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
    print('len(columns):', len(columns))

    for col in columns:
        print('click:', col.text.strip())
        col.click()
    
    # TODO: click subcategory, select checkboxes, click back button 
    subcategories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-list-item[.//icon[@key="icon_caret_right"]]')
    print('len(subcategories):', len(subcategories))
    for sub in subcategories:
        sub.click()
        
        subcolumns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[3]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
        
        for subc in subcolumns:
            subc.click()
            
    backbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-dialog-1"]/column-panel/div/dialog-layout/div/mat-dialog-content/div/div/div[1]/button')   
    backbutton.click()  
        
        
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Apply Changes"]').click()
```

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use it in wrong moment. You click it in every category but you have to click it only when you selecte subcategories.

I needed different `ID` - `dialog-0` instead of `dialog-1` and I used  shorter XPath.

```
for sub in subcategories:
    sub.click()
    
    subcolumns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[3]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
    
    for subc in subcolumns:
        subc.click()

if subcategories:               
    backbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-dialog-0"]//mat-dialog-content//button')   
    backbutton.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! 2 questions: 1) why did you need `dialog-0` instead of `dialog-1`?? I just copied the Xpath from the html element. 2) what is the "if" statement actually saying (the logic) in the code??? because I was looking to use it but didn't know how to apply it to the end of ``subcategories`` loop

Comment: in my browser it shows `id="mat-dialog-0"` not `id="mat-dialog-1"` - maybe it uses different names for different browsers or different userss - to make scraping harder. `if subcategories:` checks if `bool(subcategories)` gives `True` and it gives `True` when `subcategories != 0` and `subcategories != ""` and `subcategories is not None` and `len(subcategories) > 0`

Comment: Last thing: @furas how would I incorporate a next page button to collect company info from the remaining pages ?